# How to grep-inverse-match and exclude "before" and "after" lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Consider a text file with the following entries:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
```

Given a pattern (e.g. `fff`), I would like to grep the file above to get in the output:

```
all_lines except (pattern_matching_lines  U (B lines_before) U (A lines_after))
```

For example, if `B = 2` and `A = 1`, the output with pattern = `fff` should be:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
hhh
iii
```

How can I do this with grep or other command line tools?

---

Note, when I try:

```
grep -v 'fff'  -A1 -B2 file.txt
```

I don't get what I want. I instead get:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
--
--
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

don's might be better in most cases, but just in case the file is *really* big, and you can't get `sed` to handle a script file that large *(which can happen at around 5000+ lines of script)*, here it is with plain `sed`:

```sh
sed -ne:t -e"/\n.*$match/D" \
    -e'$!N;//D;/'"$match/{" \
            -e"s/\n/&/$A;t" \
            -e'$q;bt' -e\}  \
    -e's/\n/&/'"$B;tP"      \
    -e'$!bt' -e:P  -e'P;D'
```

This is an example of what is called a *sliding window* on input. It works by building a *look-ahead* buffer of `$B`-count lines before ever attempting to print anything.

And actually, probably I should clarify my previous point: the primary performance limiter for both this solution and don's will be directly related to interval. This solution will slow with larger interval *sizes*, whereas don's will slow with larger interval *frequencies*. In other words, even if the input file is very large, if the actual interval occurrence is still very infrequent then his solution is probably the way to go. However, if the interval size is relatively manageable, and is likely to occur often, then this is the solution you should choose.

So here's the workflow:

- If `$match` is found in pattern space preceded by a `\n`ewline, `sed` will recursively `D`elete every `\n`ewline that precedes it.

  - I was clearing `$match`'s pattern space out completely before - but to easily handle overlap, leaving a landmark seems to work far better.
  - I also tried `s/.*\n.*\($match\)/\1/` to try to get it in one go and dodge the loop, but when `$A/$B` are large, the `D`elete loop proves considerably faster.
- Then we pull in the `N`ext line of input preceded by a `\n`ewline delimiter and try once again to `D`elete a `/\n.*$match/` once again by referring to our most recently used regular expression w/ `//`.
- If pattern space matches `$match` then it can only do so with `$match` at the head of the line - all `$B`efore lines have been cleared.

  - So we start looping over `$A`fter.
  - Each run of this loop we'll attempt to `s///`ubstitute for `&`itself the `$A`th `\n`ewline character in pattern space, and, if successful, `t`est will branch us - and our whole `$A`fter buffer - out of the script entirely to start the script over from the top with the next input line if any.
  - If the `t`est is not successful we'll `b`ranch back to the `:t`op label and recurse for another line of input - possibly starting the loop over if `$match` occurs while gathering `$A`fter.
- If we get past a `$match` function loop, then we'll try to `p`rint the `$`last line if this is it, and if `!`not try to `s///`ubstitute for `&`itself the `$B`th `\n`ewline character in pattern space.

  - We'll `t`est this, too, and if it is successful we'll branch to the `:P`rint label.
  - If not we'll branch back to `:t`op and get another input line appended to the buffer.
- If we make it to `:P`rint we'll `P`rint then `D`elete up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space and rerun the script from the top with what remains.

And so this time, if we were doing `A=2 B=2 match=5; seq 5 | sed...`

The pattern space for the first iteration at `:P`rint would look like:

```
^1\n2\n3$
```

And that's how `sed` gathers its `$B`efore buffer. And so `sed` prints to output `$B`-count lines *behind* the input it has gathered. This means that, given our previous example, `sed` would `P`rint *`1`* to output, and then `D`elete that and send back to the top of the script a pattern space which looks like:

```
^2\n3$
```

...and at the top of the script the `N`ext input line is retrieved and so the next iteration looks like:

```
^2\n3\n4$
```

And so when we find the first occurrence of `5` in input, the pattern space actually looks like:

```
^3\n4\n5$
```

Then the `D`elete loop kicks in and when it's through it looks like:

```
^5$
```

And when the `N`ext input line is pulled `sed` hits EOF and quits. By that time it has only ever `P`rinted lines 1 and 2.

Here's an example run:

```sh
A=8 B=7 match='[24689]0'
seq 100 |
sed -ne:t -e"/\n.*$match/D" \
    -e'$!N;//D;/'"$match/{" \
            -e"s/\n/&/$A;t" \
            -e'$q;bt' -e\}  \
    -e's/\n/&/'"$B;tP"      \
    -e'$!bt' -e:P  -e'P;D'
```

That prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
29
30
31
32
49
50
51
52
69
70
71
72
99
100
```

Comment: I'm actually working with huge files, and don's answer was noticeably slower than this solution. I was initially hesitant to change my accepted answer, but the speed difference is quite visible.

Comment: @Amelio - this will work with a stream of any size, and it need not read the file through to work. The biggest performance factor is the size of `$A` and/or `$B`. The larger you make those numbers, the slower it will get - but you can make them reasonably large.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina - if you're using the older one, this is better, I think.

Comment: B=0 not work: sed: -e expression #7, char 8: number option to `s' command may not be zero (like i don't want to filter before the match line, only after...)

Comment: @anilech try not defining `$B`

Answer (score 17):

You could use `gnu grep` with `-A` and `-B` to print exactly the parts of the file you want to exclude but add the `-n` switch to also print the line numbers and then format the output and pass it as a command script to `sed` to delete those lines:

```
grep -n -A1 -B2 PATTERN infile | \
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1d/p' | \
sed -f - infile
```

This should also work with files of patterns passed to `grep` via `-f` e.g.:

```
grep -n -A1 -B2 -f patterns infile | \
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1d/p' | \
sed -f - infile
```

I think this could be slightly optimized if it collapsed any three or more consecutive line numbers into ranges so as to have e.g. `2,6d` instead of `2d;3d;4d;5d;6d`... though if the input has only a few matches it's not worth doing it.

---

Other ways that don't preserve line order and are most likely slower:
with `comm`:

```
comm -13 <(grep PATTERN -A1 -B2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s: infile) | sort) \
<(nl -ba -nrz -s: infile | sort) | cut -d: -f2-
```

`comm` requires sorted input which means the line order would not be preserved in the final output (unless your file is already sorted) so `nl` is used to number the lines before sorting, `comm -13` prints only lines unique to *2nd FILE* and then `cut` removes the part that was added by `nl` (that is, the first field and the delimiter `:`)
with `join`:

```
join -t: -j1 -v1 <(nl -ba -nrz -s:  infile | sort) \
<(grep PATTERN -A1 -B2 <(nl -ba -nrz -s:  infile) | sort) | cut -d: -f2-
```

Comment: Thanks Don! Quick question, would you expect the solution with `comm` to be faster than the original one with `sed` and `grep` ?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina - I don't think so as it still reads the input file _twice_ (plus it does some sorting) as opposed to Mike's solution which only processes the file once.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind using `vim`:

```
$ export PAT=fff A=1 B=2
$ vim -Nes "+g/${PAT}/.-${B},.+${A}d" '+w !tee' '+q!' foo
aaa
bbb
ccc
hhh
iii
```

- `-Nes` turns on non-compatible, silent ex mode. Useful for scripting.
- [`+{command}`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%5B%2Bcmd%5D) tell vim to run `{command}` on the file.
- [`g/${PAT}/`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) - on all lines matching `/fff/`. This gets tricky if the pattern contains regular expression special characters that you didn't intend to treat that way.
- `.-${B}` - from 1 line above this one
- `.+${A}` - to 2 lines below this one (see [`:he cmdline-ranges`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) for these two)
- [`d`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Adel) - delete the lines.
- `+w !tee` then writes to standard output.
- `+q!` quits without saving changes.

You can skip the variables and use the pattern and numbers directly. I used them just for clarity of purpose.

Answer (score 7):

How about (using GNU `grep` and `bash`):

```
$ grep -vFf - file.txt < <(grep -B2 -A1 'fff' file.txt)
aaa
bbb
ccc
hhh
iii
```

Here we are finding the lines to be discarded by `grep -B2 -A1 'fff' file.txt`, then using this as an input file to find the desired lines discarding these.

Comment: Hmm, this does not output anything on my machine (OS X)

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina sorry about that..i did not know your OS before..anyway i have tested this on Ubuntu..

Comment: This would have the same problem as `kos`'s (now deleted) solution as if there are duplicate lines in the input file and some of them fall outside the range and others are inside that range this will delete them all. Also, with multiple occurrences of _pattern_, if there are lines like `--` in the input file (outside the ranges) this will delete them because the delimiter `--` appears in `grep`'s output when more then one line is matching _pattern_ (the latter is highly unlikely but worth mentioning I guess).

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks..you are right..although i was taking OP's example literally..i am gonna leave it in case someone find it helpful later..

Answer (score 1):

You can reach a good-enough result by using temporary files:

```
my_file=file.txt #or =$1 if in a script

#create a file with all the lines to discard, numbered
grep -n -B1 -A5 TBD "$my_file" |cut -d\  -f1|tr -d ':-'|sort > /tmp/___"$my_file"_unpair

#number all the lines
nl -nln "$my_file"|cut -d\  -f1|tr -d ':-'|sort >  /tmp/___"$my_file"_all

#join the two, creating a file with the numbers of all the lines to keep
#i.e. of those _not_ found in the "unpair" file
join -v2  /tmp/___"$my_file"_unpair /tmp/___"$my_file"_all|sort -n > /tmp/___"$my_file"_lines_to_keep

#eventually use these line numbers to extract lines from the original file
nl -nln $my_file|join - /tmp/___"$my_file"_lines_to_keep |cut -d\  -f2- > "$my_file"_clean
```

The result is *good-enough* because you can loose some indentation in the process, but if it is an xml or indentation insensitive file it should not be a problem.
Since this script uses a ram drive, writing and reading those temp files is as fast as working in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you just want to exclude some lines ahead of a given marker, you could use:

```
awk -v nlines=2 '/Exception/ {for (i=0; i<nlines; i++) {getline}; next} 1'
```

(glenn jackman at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1492538 )

By piping some commands you can get the before/after behaivour:

```
awk -v nlines_after=5 '/EXCEPTION/ {for (i=0; i<nlines_after; i++) {getline};print "EXCEPTION" ;next} 1' filename.txt|\
tac|\
awk -v nlines_before=1 '/EXCEPTION/ {for (i=0; i<nlines_before; i++) {getline}; next} 1'|\
tac
```

Comment: Brilliant, use `awk` on a reversed file to handle following lines when you mean to affect lines before and re-reverse the result.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this, maybe the easiest way would be to create a variable and do the following:

```
grep -v "$(grep "fff" -A1 -B2 file.txt)" file.txt
```

This way you still have your structure. And you can easily see from the one liner what are you trying to remove.

```
$ grep -v "$(grep "fff" -A1 -B2 file.txt)" file.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
hhh
iii
```

Comment: same solution as heemayl, and same problem as described by don_crissti: This would have the same problem as kos's (now deleted) solution as if there are duplicate lines in the input file and some of them fall outside the range and others are inside that range this will delete them all. Also, with multiple occurrences of pattern, if there are lines like -- in the input file (outside the ranges) this will delete them because the delimiter -- appears in grep's output when more then one line is matching pattern (the latter is highly unlikely but worth mentioning I guess).

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 1 match:

```
A=1; B=2; n=$(grep -n 'fff' file.txt | cut -d: -f1)
head -n $((n-B-1)) file.txt ; tail -n +$((n+A+1)) file.txt
```

Otherwise (awk):

```
# -vA=a -vB=b -vpattern=pat must be provided
BEGIN{

    # add file again. assume single file
    ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[ARGC-1]
    ++ARGC
}

# the same as grep -An -Bn pattern
FNR==NR && $0 ~ pattern{
    for (i = 0; i <= B; ++i)
        a[NR-i]++
    for (i = 1; i <= A; ++i)
        a[NR+i]++
}

FNR!=NR && !(FNR in a)
```