# How can I remove certain lines and surrounding lines from a file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I've got a tcpdump file.

I want to remove certain packets. They are easy to spot because they have

```
0x0000: a6a6 a6a6 a6a6 a6a6 ........
```

as the first line of data.

The full packet looks (*mutatis mutandis*) like:

```
16:24:46.132673 00:35:1a:71:91:37 (oui Unknown) > 05:05:05:c5:05:05 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x88be), length 60: 
    0x0000:  a6a6 a6a6 a6a6 a6a6 0101 2400 00b4 b83e
    0x0010:  931f 00be 7c80 545a 0202 0000 0000 00a5
    0x0020:  a5a5 a500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So what I'd like to say is:

"Remove lines that contain this pattern, and the line before the pattern, and the two lines after it".

Sed or awk or grep would be good, *e.g.*

```
$ sed -i 'magic' file
```

Any ideas what goes in place of magic?

Comment: I think the answer to my question is 'grep can do this, see this question'. The hard bit is realising that grep is good enough and you don't have to do clever awk things.

Comment: No, the hard bit is realising `grep` alone _cannot_ do this.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the original had worked, but I was diffing the wrong files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is '**use vim**', and there are details here:

[How to grep-inverse-match and exclude "before" and "after" lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213385/how-to-grep-inverse-match-and-exclude-before-and-after-lines)

```
$ vim -Nes "+g/a6a6\ a6a6/.-1,.+2d" '+w !tee' '+q!' file >newfile
```