# Deleting a range of n lines before and after a matched line in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

In vim I can use...

`:g/match/-1d`

...several times to delete more than one line from before a match...

...and combine it with a few calls to...

`:g/match/+1d`

...to delete more than one line after the match...

`:g/match/-1d,+1d`

...to delete before after and current lines...

can the same be done with sed?

Comment: In that fashion. `-1d` and `+1d`, no, but I'm pretty sure it can be done by adjusting the regex. Can you give us a sample file and desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep-inverse-match and exclude "before" and "after" lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213385/how-to-grep-inverse-match-and-exclude-before-and-after-lines). The accepted answer there shows how to do it with `sed`.

Comment: Not a duplicate: The given answer also deletes the matched line itself

Comment: @leeand00: What `vim` version supports that `-1d,+1d` syntax?

Comment: The `:g/match/-1d,+1d` part of the Question does imply to me that the intention is to delete the matched line (as part of the range).

Comment: @Philippos: Clearly (IMO) a typo for ``-1,+1d``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for sed, but `ed` can do this as well:

```
$ seq 10 > input
$ ed -s input <<< '/5/ -2, /5/ +2 d'$'\n'w
$ cat input
1
2
8
9
10
```

This tells ed to `s`ilently edit the `input` file with two commands:

1. starting at the line that matches the regex `5`, minus two lines and ending at the line that matches the regex `5`, plus two lines, `d`elete that range

(separated with an ANSI-escaped newline `$'\n'`)

2. `w`rite the file back to disk

Comment: This is one of those use cases where the standard editor is more suitable than a stream editor.

Comment: Jeff, this needs to be done globally so the command sequence should start with a `g` I think (I can't test though as I have no `ed` here)... but even then, @AnthonyGeoghegan , this has the same problems/limitations as the `sed` solution below: it works as long as the ranges don't overlap. Use `printf %s\\n {1..5} 5 5 {5..9} >input` to produce an input sample...

Comment: Interesting; I see [muru already came up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213394/117549) the same idea as I just did. The question of overlapping "matches" seems to be a good one to clarify here.

Comment: @leeand00 I see you accepted this answer; are you OK with the limitations that don_crissti pointed out above?  I didn't test this answer with overlapping ranges. (Besides the fact that I answered with `ed` vs `sed`!)

Answer (score 1):

If the regions don't overlap, you can use

```
sed -zE 's/([^\n]*\n){2}([^\n]*match[^\n]*)(\n[^\n]*){3}/\2/g'
```

with GNU `sed`, to remove two lines before and three after the match (the values in the `{}`).

With general `sed` implementations, you don't have option `-z`, so you need to collect lines in the buffer with the `H;1h;$!d` scheme, and can't do "everything but newline" with `[^\n]`, so you need a workaround like this:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n#/#\n/;s/([^#]*#){2}([^#]*match[^#]*)(#[^#]*){3}/\2/g;y/\n#/#\n/'
```

Both solutions work on the whole file in the pattern space, so don't use this for huge files.