# How can I delete the rows after a specific grep line in BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this output from Linux.

```
Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM01

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM02

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM03

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM04

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM05

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM06

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM07

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM08

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM09

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM10

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM11

Size: No Module Installed
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM12
```

This is to diagnose DIMMs. I would like to remove the outputs from the DIMMs that say "No Module Installed. so when I run the command it will look like this:

```
Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM01

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM03

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU0
Bank Locator: DIMM05

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM07

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM09

Size: 8192 MB
Locator: CPU1
Bank Locator: DIMM11
```

The 'Locator:' and 'Bank Locator:' result is not always the same, so I would need to identify the 'Size: No Memory Installed' and then remove the following 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you, a simpler way to do this would be to only show the information for lines containing a valid size and then include the 2 lines (or 3 if you want the blank line) above it. Based on your output above that would be as easy as:
`your_output_command | grep -E "Size: [0-9]* MB" -A 2`

This would match on lines containing the regular expression `Size: [0-9]* MB` where `[0-9]*` represents any amount of digits and because of the `-A 2` also print out the 2 lines after that match.

If there is a chance the size of the DIMMS is reported in more than just MB, you the regular expression could be updated to allow for that. E.g. if MB and GB were both possibilities then it would be: `your_output_command | grep -E "Size: [0-9]* [GM]B" -A 2`.

If you definitely need to filter things based on an inverse match, I think this question: [How to grep-inverse-match and exclude "before" and "after" lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213385/how-to-grep-inverse-match-and-exclude-before-and-after-lines)  has answers that would work, but it is considerably more complicated than matching only what you want and including other lines based on that.

Answer updated based on Malte Skoruppa 's comment

Comment: That would still include all of the lines which is what is already being received.

Comment: While I agree with this answer in spirit, the sections which have `No module installed` also have that `Bank Location: DIMM` line, so it does not solve the OP's problem. Better to grep for `Size: .* MB` and then use `-A 2` as in `your_output_command | grep -E "Size: .* MB" -A 2`

Comment: Totally agree, that was just lack of attention to detail on my part and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Treat *newline newline* as a record separator. Match on records that do not contain "No Module Installed":

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n"; ORS=RS } !/No Module Installed/' dimmsfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/Size: No Module Installed/,/^$/d' file
```